# catalogue product without shopping car, and tab system Php/Sql

Tags: php, sql

I'm developping a website and I'm looking for a PHP script with an admin interface to do a product catalogue. I don't need any cart and price, just a way to display different products with different filters. With a tab system in the product description. ( It's website full coded, I'm not using any CMS such as wordpress or Joomla for that).

I've been looking like crazy but I can not find any script doing this . ..  If anybody have some suggestions, it will be amazing =).

Thank you in advance for your suggestion

Comment: You want a product catalog without any feature. Did you search around image viewer ? It seems most useful for your use...

Comment: I'm gonna deed a filter area like see on this picture: http://thinktankaadrl.com/02.jpg

and once you click on read more, a tab system for the description of the picture like here: http://thinktankaadrl.com/03.jpg

If you have any recommmandations =)